# Deserialize complex JSON data in C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I'm just an amateur in C# programming. Now i have a JSON data that looks like following

```
{
  type: "xxx",
  width: "xxx",
  dataSource: {
      "chart": {
          "caption": "xxx"
       },
      "data": [
       {},
       {} 
      ]
  } 
}
```

I'm having the whole data as escaped string. now after Unescape when I'm using JavaScriptSerializer as follows

```
var data = ser.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, Object>>(chartData);
```

I'm able to get the "type", "width" as

```
data["width"]
data["type"]
```

Now I have to get the value of "caption". Any suggestion how to get that, I believe the dictionary structure need to be changed but I'm stacked for my lack of knowledge in C#

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I parse JSON with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Comment: Try this site: http://json2csharp.com/ it convert json to c# classes. Its awesome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the object's scheme you man want to create a class that represents in and then deserialize the json into it:

```
YourKnownClass obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourKnownClass>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.dataSource.chart.caption.Value);
```

Another option is by using a dynamic type (There is no good reason using a dynamic object if you know the schema and can create a matching C# class. This has a performance impact as well):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.dataSource.chart.caption.Value);
```

BTW, In this example i'm using json.net which is a popular library.

Comment: You should mention that you use an external library called Json.NET instead of the built-in deserializer.